# Burp suite and Fiddler cannot intercept traffic

Tags: http, fiddler, debugger

I apologize in advance for my English :P.

I have a problem. Burp suite and Fiddler(Classic/Everywhere) cannot intercept traffic from the program. However Http debugger and Http analyzer can do this, but the functionality of these programs is not enough for me.

[image]

Comment: What program on what OS?

Comment: Win 10 21h2, The program is cheat loader.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need to understand why this is happening, possibly due to incorrect Burp/Fiddler settings, and help set it up correctly